# Symfony 3, login form created in login controller

Tags: php, symfony

I would like create login form in symfony with in controller. Something like this.

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login_controller")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(new User)
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'name' => '_username'
                )
            ))
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'name' => '_password'
                )
            ))
            ->add('login', ButtonType::class)
            ->add('logout', ButtonType::class)
            ->getForm();

    return $this->render('login/login.html.twig', array(
        'error' => $error,
        'lastUsername' => $lastUsername,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

and twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

After press login button nothig happens... But if I use instead of in twig

```
<form action="{{ path('login_controller') }}" method="POST">

    <label for="username">username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="_username" id="username" value="{{ lastUsername }}" />

    <br />

    <label for="password">password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="_password" id="password" />

    <br />

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>

<br />
```

All works well... Some idea pls?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that your form_* functions produce?

Comment: <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" name="_username" />

<button type="button" id="form_logout" name="form[logout]">Logout</button>

The rest of the code is a classic html form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i got it... My mistake, I should use SubmitType instead of ButtonType

Answer (score 0):

going from the docs 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html

The Submit button has an additional method isClicked() that lets you check whether this button was used to submit the form. This is especially useful when a form has multiple submit buttons

```
$builder->add('login', ButtonType::class, array(
));

if ($form->get('login')->isClicked()) {
    // ...
}
```